# ubuntu snap eclipse loses reference during runtime

Tags: snap, vmware, eclipse

I got some problems with eclipse running on a Ubuntu VMware. During runtime, while active in eclipse or even runnnig passive in te backround the internal snap reference seems to break somehow.
The folder reference /snap/eclipse/40 just disappears and a new .../61 folder appears. Eclipse shows several error if still opened, code editor and file explorer still working. Software must be shutdown hard and can't be opened again as the reference is missing (folder 40)

The used eclipse version is:
Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200

There seems to be another instance of eclipse installed to the system:
Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212

~/snap/eclipse$ ls
40  48  common  current

Ubuntu V18.04

Anyone expierence a similar issue and knows how to fix it? I'm new in the company and wanted to work with this VM copy of a collegue. He has no issues with "same" VM on his system. My other solution would be to setup a new VM.

Regards

Comment: A new VM and a clean install of the app might be the fastest solution.

Comment: indeed it was. But I thought it's worth a try maybe someone else had this problem